# Physically sharing 5v and ground between multiple sensors

Tags: power, soldering, ground

I'm using the Adafruit Trinket with two sensors that both need to be connected to power/ground pins (Trinket has one 5v output power and one ground). The final size of a whole thing matters so I cannot use stripboards (at least as a whole). What is the physically smallest way to share the 5v and ground between the sensors? Can I just solder multiple wires into one hole?

[image: Trinket]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could solder as many wires into the whole as will fit. You could also solder a pigtail onto the ground then crimp the wires you need to that. Assuming you aren't using high power, high frequency or overly sensitive sensors neither option should cause any issues.